# C# Default Format For Comma-Delimited Numbers

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I have a C# application that displays some large numbers in a textbox.  I want it to use a comma as a thousands separator.  I use the following code to do that:

```
 txtNumberDisplay.Text = intNumber.ToString("N0");
```

The above was working fine until recently it was displaying numbers correctly in the form of:

```
 123,456
```

Recently the thousands separator has somehow changed to a period "." and the numbers display like this:

```
 123.456
```

My first thought was the culture had somehow gotten set incorrectly but I checked the default culture for the current thread at the point it displays this number and it is set correctly to "EN-US".  Any idea why this would display a period instead of a comma?

Thanks,

Comment: You can use `InvariantCulture`: `intValue.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. How did you check the culture, show also that code.

Comment: Stefan's approach is the nicest one if you look at the formatting. Problem is, it's dependent on your current culture. If you'll pass the invariant culture into the ToString() method aswell, you will ALWAYS get a dot as delimeter. So the best way is probably a combination from Stefan and Tims answers.

Comment: @Eisenhorn: why is `string.Format("{0:#,###0}", value)` nicer than `value.ToString("N0")` apart from the fact that it does also fail with the wrong culture which seems to be the core problem?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, it allows for more complex control over your output, i.e. you could also go ahead and do this: `string.Format("{0:##,##,####}", value)`

Comment: @Eisenhorn: always use the simplest approach until you need a more complex one, otherwise you are obfuscating your code unnecessarily. Apparently the [numeric ("N") format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100).aspx#NFormatString) is exactly what OP wants.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That holds somewhat true, even though it won't hurt to know about both approaches. Personally, I think it's a simple matter of taste :)

Answer (score 2):

use string.Format:

```
int value = 1234;
string.Format(@"{0:#\,##0}", value); 

//Output will be 1,234
```

EDIT: added an \,

EDIT2: Just found out that this wont work on numbers with 6 digits (two commas would be needed), so here is a workarount, but there must be a better solution...

```
        int value = 1234;
        string s = "#";
        for (int i = 0; i < value.ToString().Length / 3; i++) s += @"\,###";

        string output = string.Format(@"{0:" + s + "}", value);
```

Comment: I thought he was talking about an int number?

Comment: im sorry, i changed double to int :)

Comment: Just nitpicking: i get `123.456.789`. My point is, how does that help to fix the culture issue? `intNumber.ToString("N0")` should work also.

Comment: Wouldn't it work just as expected if you added the invariant culture to the Format call? On the other hand, you can always handpick a culture like de_DE and pass it on to the call for a comma delimeter.

Answer (score 2):

> My first thought was the culture had somehow gotten set incorrectly but I checked the default culture for the current thread at the point it displays this number and it is set correctly to "EN-US". Any idea why this would display a period instead of a comma?

Either the culture is something different than "en-US" or you have customized the number format in the regional settings in the control panel.

When you execute `intNumber.ToString("N0")` without specifying a culture the culture used is `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`. Perhaps you examined `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` which is based on the language version of Windows and not used for formatting?

If the current culture really is "en-US" you should go to **Control Panel** -> **Clock, Language, and Region** -> **Change date, time, or number formats** and make sure that the **Digit grouping symbol** is comma and not dot. The symbol shown in the control panel is the symbol used when you do not specify a `CultureInfo` when you format the number.

You have several options:

- Force the culture when formatting, e.g. `intNumber.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to get commas as you desire.
- Realize that the user should be able to control the formatting. This is what your code currently does.

Comment: This is a very strange problem...I have checked both CultureInfo.InvariantCulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture  and both are set to "en-US".  I also browsed through those culture settings and the number separator is indeed a comma.  I went into Control Panel and checked the settings there to make sure that they had not been overridden and they are not - it is set for comma as a thousands delimiter.  I tried forcing the culture using .ToString("N0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) and I still get periods instead of commas.  Very strange!

Comment: I've done some further testing on this problem on different systems.  If I run exactly the same code on a Windows 7 system, I get commas; if I run the same code on a Windows 8 or 8.1 system, I get periods instead of commas...all of the systems are en-US culture.

Comment: @chuckc3: I do not know if it is a spelling mistake but it is `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` that matters - not those you mention in your comment. However, you also claim that even if you use `InvariantCulture` you get a dot. That is most unexpected. Please verify that `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator` is a dot (which is should be by definition). Then, if you still get a comma when using `InvariantCulture` you have evidence that your problem is somewhere else in your application.

Comment: Thanks for your response...I have checked Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and it is "en-US".  I checked CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator and it is a comma.  I have tested this app on four different machines - on three Windows 8 machines, I get a dot; on the one Windows 7 machine I tested it on, I get a comma.

Comment: I found the following code that forces the numbergroupseparator to something else:

`NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;`
`nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = "-";`

`txtNumber.Text = intNumber(“N0”, nfi)`

The above code should force the numbergroupseparator to be a hyphen and I verified that in the “nfi” format info that it is set to a hyphen (“-“) yet what is displayed in the Textbox is still a period.  It seems that no matter what I do to try to force it to display a comma, it displays a dot.

Answer (score 1):

This should work perfectly fine:

```
int.ToString("F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8.1 (and probably 8 as well) has incorrect culture regional settings stored. 
Therefore, if you rely on ToString("formatstring", desired_culture) it won't work.

Since you write

> [...] The above was working fine until recently it was displaying numbers
>   correctly [...]

I suppose in-between the working and not-working, you upgraded to Windows 8 or 8.1, which explains why it suddenly stopped working.

For example for culture German - Switzerland ("de-CH") it incorrectly sets the NumberDecimalSeparator to "," instead of "." (and the thousand-separator to " " instead of "'") and therefore copy-pasting to Excel won't work anymore (Excel seems to somehow use a non-system format).

You best hardcode your number format, because that's the only way to keep it working across windows-versions. 
This is how I do it (you might want to change the separators and the currency-symbol):

```
private static System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo SetupNumberFormatInfo()
{ 
    //System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo nfi = (System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
    System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo nfi = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();
    nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = "'";
    nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

    nfi.CurrencyGroupSeparator = "'";
    nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
    nfi.CurrencySymbol = "CHF";

    return nfi;
} // End Function SetupNumberFormatInfo


private static System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo m_nfi = SetupNumberFormatInfo();


public static string ToNumberString(this double dblQuantity)
{
    return ToNumberString(dblQuantity, "N0");
}


public static string ToNumberString(this double dblQuantity, string Format)
{
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo%28VS.71%29.aspx

    //double dblQuantity = -123456789.123456789;
    //string strFormattedInteger = dblQuantity.ToString("N0", m_nfi);
    //strFormattedInteger = string.Format(m_nfi, "{0:N0}", dblQuantity);

    return dblQuantity.ToString(Format, m_nfi);
}
```